# PowerShell switch block and values coded in 64 bits

Tags: powershell, switch-statement, 64-bit

I cannot use a PowerShell Switch statement when 64 bits integers are involved.

I have the follwing PowerShell snippet :

```
PS D:\> cat .\dirSize.ps1
$dirName = $args[0]
$dirSize = [uint64]( ( dir "$dirName" -force -recurse | measure -property length -sum ).Sum )
switch( $dirSize ) {
    { $_ -in 1tb..1pb } { "{0:n2} TiB" -f ( $dirSize / 1tb ); break }
}
```

I get this error :

```
Cannot convert value "1099511627776" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Value was either too large or too small for an Int32."
At C:\Users\sebastien.mansfeld\psh\dirSize.ps1:4 char:4
+     { $_ -in 1tb..1pb } { "{0:n2} TiB" -f ( $dirSize / 1tb ); break }
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastIConvertible
```

So I tried converting the switch test line to `uint64` but it does not work :

```
switch( $dirSize ) {
    { [uint64]$_ -in [uint64]1tb..[uint64]1pb } { "{0:n2} TiB" -f ( $dirSize / 1tb ); break }
}
```

I get the same error message.

I'm expecting the switch condition to work.

Comment: The `-in` operator, "tells whether a test value appears in a collection of reference values." So it likely converts the `..` range into an array... Even if it did support 64-bit values `1tb..1pb` would be just shy of 8 petabytes of ram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your condition for something more efficient that wont throw that out of bounds error:

```bash
switch ( $dirSize ) {
    { $_ -ge 1tb -and $_ -le 1pb } {
        '{0:n2} TiB' -f ( $dirSize / 1tb ); break 
    }
}
```

You could also make use of [`PSTree` Module](https://github.com/santisq/PSTree/tree/main) that comes with this built-in functionality, as an example, your current code would be replaced with:

```bash
(Get-PSTree $dirName -Depth 0 -RecursiveSize -Force).GetFormattedLength()
```

To install it, you can:

```bash
Install-Module PSTree -Scope CurrentUser
```

Comment: @SebMa well you have to install the module first to use it..

Comment: I did install this module as `CurrentUser` scope.

Comment: @SebMa `Import-Module PSTree` first, example: https://i.imgur.com/bgADfV9.png

Answer (score 1):

the range(`..`) only works with `[int32]` values.

Just use

```
switch ( $dirSize ) {
    # less or equal 1PB or more or equale 1TB
    { (1PB -ge $_) -and (1TB -le $_) } {
        '{0:n2} TiB' -f ( $dirSize / 1TB )
        break 
    }
    # { other comparsions } { other results }
    # default { default result }
}
```

Comment: Is there a Microsoft documentation that confirms ranges only work with `[int32]` values ?

Comment: @SebMa, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#range-operator-) currently notes, "The range operator can be used to represent an array of sequential integers [...]", which is a bit vague. I've created [GitHub docs issue #10906](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/10906) to address that.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon oops, my bad.  I even wrote "or" in the comment. Thanks for the head-ups